# I want to convert given time into miliseconds. The given time is not direct date object

Tags: javascript, string, datetime, datetime-conversion

The given time format is `'1 Day 10 Hours 10 Minutes 13 Seconds'`.
Here - it includes notation which we use to denote time units like - `Hr` or `H` or `Hours` or `Hrs`. Same for other time units also.

Is there builtin method or known this is there?

Comment: What's the format with zero values? Do you have `'1 Day 0 Hours 10 Minutes 13 Seconds'` or `'1 Day 10 Minutes 13 Seconds'`?

Comment: Yes, it can be 0 and negative also. Bu for negative we will put the restriction and show invalid given data.

Comment: If the format is not consistent, you should describe it. One example is not enough.

Comment: Converting days to milliseconds is problematic in places where daylight saving is observed as not all days are 24 hours long. :-)

Answer (score 2):

No, there is nothing built-in

You can parse it like this if the format is not consistent except order

It handles any of 4 units of at least one character starting with d,h,m,s

```js
const ms = { s : 1000, m : 60000, h : 3600000, d : 86400000 }
const strToMS = str =>  {
  const parts = str.match(/(\d+ \w)/g)
  console.log(parts);
  return parts.map(part => {
    const [num, unit] = part.split(" ");
    return num * ms[unit.toLowerCase()]
  }).reduce((a,b)=>a+b)
};

["10 Hours 13 Seconds",
"1 day",
"1 hr",
"13 Seconds",
"2 Days 10 Hours 1 Minute 3 Seconds",
"2 Days 10 Hours 1 Minute 3 Sec"]
  .forEach(timeString => console.log(timeString,strToMS(timeString)))
```

if the format is known and consistent - i.e. 8 parts: n1 day(s) n2 hour(s) n3 minute(s) n4 second(s) this script will ignore the units

```js
const aSecond = 1000, aMinute = 60 * aSecond, anHour = 60 * aMinute, aDay = 24 * anHour;

const strToMS = str =>  {
  const [days, hours, minutes, seconds] = str.match(/\d+/g)
  console.log(days, hours, minutes, seconds)
  return  days * aDay + hours * anHour + minutes * aMinute + seconds * aSecond
};

// Assuming n1 day(s) n2 hours n3 minutes n4 seconds, i.e. 8 parts

const timeString = "1 Day 10 Hours 10 Minutes 13 Seconds"

console.log(strToMS(timeString))
```

Comment: Format is known but it's not consistent. As I shown in problem statement, user can enter in following patterns. Case-1: 2 Days 10 Hours 1 Minute 3 Seconds or 2 Days 10 Hours 1 Minute 3 Sec. There are many possibilities, Is there any way to handle?

Comment: See update (no change to the script). The script that ignores how many elements works with 13 seconds too